# Paypal API Credentials Access

Tags: paypal

Hello Everyone,
              I'm using personal paypal Australian account. I want to connect my account with my website to accept payments. So i need to get Paypal API Credentials Access and this is under profile => "My Selling Tools" in my profile. My account is verified with debit card. What's the requirements to activate "My Selling Tools" => "API access" settings on my account?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** - Add or edit API permissions to view your current API settings, change your settings, or set up additional carts or online stores.

This option applies to:

- Hosted online stores and shopping carts integrated with PayPal
- Websites hosted and managed by third-party service providers

**Option 2** - Request API credentials to create your own API username and password.

This option applies to:

- Custom websites and online stores
- Pre-integrated shopping carts
  running on your own server

Source: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=%5fprofile%2dapi%2daccess&upgrade.x=1

Comment: Unfortunately "API ACCESS" option isn't available in my account. what's the requirements to activate that option?

Comment: You need merchant account.